# javascript click change color

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have such a cube I would like to click on the color changed on each wall I dont know where to start not long ago I began to learn to programming I have to use javascript onclick? 
I would like to add a function later which, for example, would change the direction of the cube while rotating

This is my code:

```css
  #scena {
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 140px;
  border: 1px solid rebeccapurple;
}

#kostka {
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: obracaniekostki 7s infinite alternate
}

.sciana {
  opacity: 0.6;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

div.front {
  background-color: aqua;
  transform: translateZ(100px);
}

div.back {
  background-color: red;
  transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(100px);
}

div.left {
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
}

div.right {
  background-color: orange;
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(100px);
}

div.top {
  background-color: purple;
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(100px);
}

div.bottom {
  background-color: rgb(68, 128, 0);
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
}

@keyframes obracaniekostki {
  from {}
  to {
    transform: rotateZ(360deg) rotateX(360deg);
  }
```

```html
<div id="scena">
  <div id="kostka">
    <div class="sciana front">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="sciana back">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="sciana left">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="sciana right">
      4
    </div>
    <div class="sciana top">
      5
    </div>
    <div class="sciana bottom">
      6
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like that?

## Edit

As you asked I have added the code to change the rotation. The trick is to change the CSS animation. If you want the transition to be fluid, you must change the code to start the second animation where the first one was stopped (this article could help: https://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/).

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.sciana')
  .forEach(faceElement => {
    faceElement.addEventListener('click', () => {

      // Do whatever you want here...

      // Gets the face of the cube...
      var face = faceElement.className
        .split(' ')
        .filter(_class => _class != 'sciana')[0];

      // Changes the color of the clicked face...
      faceElement.style.backgroundColor = 'red';     
    })
  });
  
 /* EDIT #1 */
 var cubeElement = document.querySelector('#kostka');
 cubeElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Changes the rotation by applying another animation...
  cubeElement.classList.toggle('animation-1');
  cubeElement.classList.toggle('animation-2');
 });
 /* EDIT #1 END */
```

```css
#scena {
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 140px;
  border: 1px solid rebeccapurple;
}


/* EDIT #1 */
#kostka {
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
/* EDIT #1 END */


/* EDIT #1 */
.animation-1 {
  animation: animation-1 7s infinite alternate;
}

.animation-2 {
  animation: animation-2 7s infinite alternate;
}
/* EDIT #1 END */

.sciana {
  opacity: 0.6;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

div.front {
  background-color: aqua;
  transform: translateZ(100px);
}

div.back {
  background-color: red;
  transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(100px);
}

div.left {
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
}

div.right {
  background-color: orange;
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(100px);
}

div.top {
  background-color: purple;
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(100px);
}

div.bottom {
  background-color: rgb(68, 128, 0);
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
}

/* EDIT #1 */
@keyframes animation-1 {
  from {}
  to {
    transform: rotateZ(360deg) rotateX(360deg);
  }
}
  
@keyframes animation-2 {
  from {}
  to {
    transform: rotateZ(-360deg) rotateX(-360deg);
  }
}
/* EDIT #1 END */
```

```html
<div id="scena">
  <!-- EDIT #1 -->
  <div id="kostka" class="animation-1">
    <!-- EDIT #1 END -->
    <div class="sciana front">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="sciana back">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="sciana left">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="sciana right">
      4
    </div>
    <div class="sciana top">
      5
    </div>
    <div class="sciana bottom">
      6
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: That's what I mean, and how to make it change the direction of rotation when clicking